Studio Display dims whenever video player is visible
I have a Mac Studio Display that dims the screen whenever a video player like Apple TV, IINA, … is visible on any attached screen (not only on the Studio Display).
The video player does not have to be playing, it's enough if it is visible. A couple of seconds after the player is closed or minimized the screen slowly changes to its natural brightness.
This happens independent of whether True Tone and automatic brightness are turned on or off.
Does anyone know how I can prevent this?

At the least, I can confirm that I don't have this issue on my Studio Display. Try all the usually troubleshooting: test booting to Safe Mode; test logging into a brand new user account. These will give you an indication of where the problem lies: (safe boot fix means it's some software problem at the system level; user fix means it's a user account issue.)

Have you tried it with the Apple TV app? It does not dim on web video like YouTube or Netflix for example.

Yes, I tested with Apple's Tv.app.

Okay, thank you. That's important information. I will try to get behind this.
